# undefined method `run' for main:Object (NoMethodError) Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, rack

```ruby
require 'sinatra/base'

class Foo < Sinatra::Base
  get('/foo') { 'foo' }
end

class Bar < Sinatra::Base
  get('/bar') { 'bar' }
end

run Rack::Cascade, [Foo, Bar]
```

I just can't guess what is wrong with this code.
When I ran: ruby server.rb, it throws an error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the last line should read

```
run Rack::Cascade.new [Foo, Bar]
```

But you can only use this in a Rackup File. So second, you need to create a File called config.ru (Rackup File) with the following contents:

```
require './app'
run Rack::Cascade.new [Foo, Bar]
```

and a file called app.rb with your actual app:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class Foo < Sinatra::Base
  get('/foo') { 'foo' }
end

class Bar < Sinatra::Base
  get('/bar') { 'bar' }
end
```

then you can start the server by typing in the command line

```
$ rackup
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
```

after that, open a second command line window and test your app:

```
$ curl 0.0.0.0:9292/foo
foo%
$ curl 0.0.0.0:9292/bar
bar%
```

Comment: Thanks it helped. I am new to Sinatra. In example there was "run Rack::Cascade [Foo, Bar]", without ".new". Maybe it was misspelling or previous version of sinatra used such syntax.

Comment: You're welcome. When you're only testing, you can also write all the code in config.ru, but i guess that is considered bad practice.

Comment: And is. it a good practice to make modular sinatra apps, like rails app structure with (controllers, views, helpers, lib, public folders)?

Comment: Yes! In fact, Sinatra leaves it up to you, whether you invent a full-blown modular app or simply cram everything in one file. That is the big difference to Rails, which imposes most of the structure on you.