# Start Gollum via Rack

Tags: ruby, rack, gollum-wiki

I am new to Ruby and Rack. I found a project called [Gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum). I want to set the Author and followed this [instruction](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/wiki/Gollum-via-Rack). 
I installed it via `gem install gollum`. But when I want to start the project via:

```
/gollum/config.ru
```

the commandline tells me `undefined method 'run' for main:Object`.

My `config.ru` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'gollum/app'

module Precious
  class App < Sinatra::Base
    ['/create/*','/edit/*'].each do |path|
      before path do

        session['gollum.author'] = {:name => "xxx",
                                :email => "xxx"}
      end
    end
  end
end

run Precious::App
```

Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined method \`run' for main:Object (NoMethodError) Sinatra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786540/undefined-method-run-for-mainobject-nomethoderror-sinatra)

Comment: Ok, this helped me I little bit. Now I got `Switch to inspect mode`. Btw I am running it from a docker-container